# 3d image editor library for rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, rubygems, editor

I'm looking for the library that will allow us to create a 3d editor for the custom product on a web app.

There are few requirements:
 - User can apply colors / patterns from the palette
 - User can manipulate 3d object 
 - User can upload image and apply it to the product design

There and examples of what we're going to build:

https://kreator.zapakuj.to

http://www.packaging-works.co.uk/BoxDesigner

Does anyone have an experience / idea, of what we could use for that purpose?

Comment: Hi @karol-michalski, did you get ahead with this project?